# xss-clean middleware in my website is working on one page but not working on the other

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use xss-clean middleware in my site but that is working only on one portion of site and not the other. The middleware is sanitizing inputs for "ratings" route but not for "upload" route. What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks.

```
const express= require('express');

const ratelimit= require('express-rate-limit');
const xss= require('xss-clean')

upload_rate_limit = ratelimit({
    windowMs: 10 * 60 * 1000,
    max: 10,
    message: "Too many places and photos added. Try again later"
}) 


// App Middlewares
app= express();
app.use(express.json({limit: '10kb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(xss());
app.use('/upload/', upload_rate_limit);


// Custom modules

const upload = require('./upload');

const rating= require('./rating');




// Routes

app.use('/upload', upload); //Where User uploads Data
app.use('/rating', rating); //Takes User Input of Ratings
```

Answer (score 0):

Nvm got it. The express middleware was messing up with the xss middleware, I called xss middleware inside the upload route after express json limit and it worked